# How to define a variable which is every file except this one

Tags: makefile

I am using gnu make.

I have a rule like this:

```
SOURCES=*.in

output:$(SOURCES)
    $(PROCESSOR) -i $(SOURCES)
```

This works well. Now I need to exclude one file, test.in, from SOURCES, how should I update the rule above?

[**UPDATE**]
Actually the problem changes a bit, I need to read an environment variable, based on its value, I either take all files with ".in" as postfix or exclude test.in.

Could you show me how to do this?

Comment: Name the one file with a different suffix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some of the [built-in functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions):

```
SOURCES := $(filter-out $(if $(filter val,$(env_var)),test.in),$(wildcard *.in))
```

If you only want this to apply to that single rule:

```
output: $(filter-out $(if $(filter val,$(env_var)),test.in),$(SOURCES))
```

where `env_var` is the environment value to check, and `val` the value. If you want a partial match then replace `filter` with `findstr`. You can split the definition into multiple statements and / or `ifeq` if the one-liner is too cryptic.

Comment: Thanks user657267, I updated the question, could you help out?